# Форматирование файла excel в csv 'python' c изменением имени исходного файла

Tags: python, pandas

Нужна помощь, есть папка где сохраняется файл в формате xls, моя задача переcохранить в формате csv, где разделитель должен быть ";" . Пробовал через такой код

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(path_file\Number.csv', dtype=str)

df.to_csv(path_file\Number.csv', index = False)
```

файл пересохраняет в нужном формате без изменения имени файла (

Любой ответ с примером кода будет полезен, заранее благодарю!

Comment: ну так надо бы при сохранении указать другое имя, а не то же. Ясень пень, что если сохранять с таким же именем, то с таким же и сохранится. Код, кстати, не соответствует тому, что написано в тексте. С ошибкой, к тому же.

Comment: вопрос, как доработать код чтобы при сохранении файл пере сохранялся под другим именем, так как в исходном файле имя файла не изменяется , но все что внутри обновляется ежедневно. Спасибо за оперативный ответ и замечания касательно ошибок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel('path_file\Number.xlsx', dtype=str)

df.to_csv(f"path_file\{datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}.xlsx", index=False, sep=';')
```

Или так:

```
import xlrd
import csv

def csv_from_excel():
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Number.xlsx')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    your_csv_file = open('another.csv', 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    your_csv_file.close()

csv_from_excel()
```

Или можно ещё так:

```
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('number.xlsx')
sh = wb.active
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline=""):
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for r in sh.rows:
        c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

Последние 2 способа лучше, потому что не используется - (pandas) который весит под 100 метров, (и тянет в зависимостях numpy, который весит примерно столько же), что бы сделать такую простую задачу.

А ещё пандас законвертирует вам все нули, так что можно потерять некоторые данные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Подскажите пожалуйста, в Вашем примере как можно применить изменение названия файла на дату, ну к примеру если вход  'number.xlsx' то при выходе чтобы был примерно так 31.08.2022.csv , возможно ли это?

Comment: Да, конечно. Обновил 1 ответ. По аналогии можете сделать и в других способах! Но лучше вместо точек в названии файлов где используются даты, использовать "-"

Comment: Учусь на ошибках и примерах ( , вопрос, почему при использовании 1 примера у меня файл сохраняется в виде {datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')} , может я не так понял или недопонял всего.....

Comment: Вы сказали вам дату указать в имени файла. Я сейчас поправил, заметил что я не добавил вам .xlsx формат в конце. {} в f string это интерполяция значения в строку.